# Installed XFCE on Kubuntu, now getting duplicate lock screen login

Tags: 14.04, kubuntu, 64-bit, xfce

I installed the `xfce-desktop` package in order to give myself a lighter GUI to improve the performance of Kerbal Space Program -- and KSP now works great!  However, since first logging into the XFCE Session or Xubuntu session, every time my screen locks (manual or timed) while logged into KDE Plasma I get an XFCE login, *followed by* a KDE login to unlock the screen.  I'm also seeing the XFCE login screen when fresh starting the system, and I'd much rather have the KDE Plasma login.

If it matters, I'm on a Core2Duo, 8 GB RAM, nVidia GTx950 w/ 1 GB.  Everything was working fine before installed XFCE, except (I was told) the load from KDE Plasma was affecting my game's performance.

```
$ sudo dpkg-reconfigure kdm
dpkg-query: package 'kdm' is not installed and no information is available
Use dpkg --info (= dpkg-deb --info) to examine archive files,
and dpkg --contents (= dpkg-deb --contents) to list their contents.
/usr/sbin/dpkg-reconfigure: kdm is not installed
```

I'm pretty sure I've had `lightdm` from installation of 14.04, rather than `kdm` -- and `lightdm` is still present (shows in task list).

How can I correct this?

Comment: Will try it when I get home.

Comment: @DavidFoerster Looks like kdm is MIA.  I have a hunch reinstalling it will make xfce fail similarly...

Comment: I'm pretty sure I've always had `lightdm` rather than `kdm`.

Comment: I ran your command with `lightdm` subbed for `kdm` and got a return to command prompt without any message.  Still have the duplicate screen unlock, can't tell yet if other issues were improved.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/53737/discussion-between-zeiss-ikon-and-david-foerster).

Comment: @DavidFoerster Installed `kdm` and it seems to have fixed the duplicate logins from screen lock.  Still need to check that XFCE works right, and it'd be nice to get my login splash back.  Why does everyone like "ugly" as a preferred look these days?

Comment: I guess it's called the "greeter" -- but I already found instructions on how to select the greeter I want, and long ago I found something that set it to use an image I selected.  And now I know how to switch back and forth between `kdm`, `lightdm`, etc. as needed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turned out that for some reason KDM was removed. To reinstall it:

```
sudo apt install kdm
```

If KDM is installed but disabled in favour of a different display manager, e. g. LightDM, you can reconfigure KDM as the default again:

```
sudo dpkg-reconfigure kdm
```